# Android Studio - The user interface location changes when the system language changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface

I just finished a simple app, but when I change my phone to another language, like Hebrew, for example, the UI place changes. How can I fix it?

English view:
[The UI when the system language is English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YrIH.jpg)

Hebrew view:
[The UI when the system language is Hebrew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27KvE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats right-to-left layout positioning due to RTL language set on device. note that even icons on top status bar are changing order. you can disable this behavior via manifest entry

```
<manifest>
    <application
        ....
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
    // activities, services, broadcasts etc. in here
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) you have some doc about that topic, [HERE](https://medium.com/android-news/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2) some useful blog post